# Windows 10 Logon using smartcard - Missing Driver

Tags: smartcard, pkcs

I am trying to log in to a domain account using smart card work but was not successful.

I have the following environment setup for the test.

Client Laptop (Lenovo P50)

- Windows 10 Fall Creator
- Windows Update: Up to date
- Installed the smart card middleware
- Using the default smart card reader "Microsoft Usbccid Smartcard Reader (WUDF)"
- Domain Server (Hyper-V VM hosted on the client laptop)

Windows server 2016

- Windows Update: Up to date
- Installed the smart card middleware
- Active Directory Certificate Services

  1. Installed Certificate Authority
  2. Installed Certificate Authority Web Enrollment
  3. Installed Online Responder
- Created the smart card template using the vendor CSP and included the created smart card template to be issue

I have managed to import the certificate into the smart card via web enrollment. However, when I try to login to Windows 10 using the smart card option, I receive the error message "**The smart card requires drivers that is not present in the system. Please try another smart card or contact your administrator**"

I have also tried using a different machine running Windows 10 Anniversary but I still got the same error message.

Additional information: Before obtaining the latest middleware from the vendor, I was not able to import the certificate to the smart card. I received the same error message (mentioned above) as when I try to log in.

Any idea on how to resolve the login error?

Thanks